# Default timezone for DateTime in asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

What determines the default timezone for a DateTime instance if no timezone is specified.
Example:
A user living in timezone A visits a webpage hosted on a server in timezone B:
If the website code calls ToUniversalTime() on a dateTime instance, will timezone A or timezone B be used as the bases for the calculation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTTP does not send client time zones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `DateTime` operations occur in the server's local timezone, or in UTC.

ASP.Net is completely unaware of the user's time zone.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Unless the client time is explicitly passed to the server.  In other words, you "could" send the client time if you wanted, but by default it doesn't happen.

Comment: @DanPichelman: You could only do that by modifying the client.  And there is no way to tell .Net to use a different time zone.