# Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Time zone issue when getting events

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am getting Events with below code:

```
       EventsResource.ListRequest req = service.Events.List(calresult[i].Id);
       DateTime minLimit = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
       DateTime maxLimit = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
       req.TimeZone = googleapiTimezone; //Pacific/Honolulu
       req.TimeMin = minLimit;
       req.TimeMax = maxLimit;
       var events = req.Execute().Items;
```

The code is working find except it is not considering the Timezone parameter in any case it returns the Event DateTime info in the default event timezone.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It says that all `DateTime` operations occur in the server's local timezone, or in UTC. `ASP.Net` is completely unaware of the user's time zone. You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658039/default-timezone-for-datetime-in-asp-net) for more info.

Comment: Sorry not related to my question i know the timezone and i am passing it on to google but not getting the desired results it still send event datetime back in the default event timezone.